# How to connect my subdomin to Route 53 Record Set to different port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Ihave created an instance `t3.micro` on AWS and I have installed `vesta control panel`.

I have connected my ec2 instance to CloudFront and thereby connecting it to route 53.

My problem is when I visit `mydomain.com:port` It's showing `page not found` but when I visit using `IP:port` it's working.

My question is how can I route my `subdomain.mywebsite.com` to `mydomain.com:port` in route 53.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Did you register a domain name with Amazon Route 53? Whose IP address did you use to visit your website that worked?

Comment: I have registered my domain using GoDaddy but I have configured my nameservers to use route53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a resource record in your Route 53 hosted zone, so that the domain name you want to use for your website can be resolved to the address of either the CloudFront distribution domain or EC2 instance, depending on how you host your site. To use a [custom domain name with CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html), you need to add an alternate domain name to your distribution.

Comment: I have created all the records and my domain is working but my control panel is in port 8083 which I am not able to access. Ex: `mydomain.com:8083` this is not working

Comment: Then you have to append the port to the domain, i.e. http://subdomain.mywebsite.com:port.

Comment: can you please tell me how to append it

Comment: I suspect the resource record you claimed to have created is not correct. What dns type of record (A or CNAME) did you create for your website domain name?

Comment: I have created A record which is addressing CloudFront distribution domain

Comment: To use a custom domain name with CloudFront, check the document at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the origin [HTTP/HTTPS ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesHTTPPort) in your CloudFront configuration.

It does not blindly proxy the traffic, it will be instead trying to connect on the port.

Changing this will allow you to connect CloudFront on port 80 for HTTP or port 443 for HTTPS, but with the traffic in the back end forwarded to the correct port.